# Lottie animation from JSON file in Wordpress custom theme

Tags: wordpress, lottie, bodymovin

I’ve been searching for a while and there seems not to be much information on How to do it.

I’m looking to embed a Lottie animation file from a prepared JSON file on a Wordpress page without using any plugin.

I technically know, that I need a Lottie `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page file
And get the file itself in the  tag plus install the package through yarn.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around by uploading the lottie file to app.lottiefiles.com and using code tags from there.

However, if someone knows a way how to implement the lottie file in the code without using the external website, please share.